# combine two query results into one with conditions in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two query to combine two results into one. However; my challenge is to get the second query look into the first query if it doesn't exist in the first query.

I changed my post to the actual query

```
   SELECT        Name.CO_ID, Name.FULL_NAME, Name.ID, rpt.date AS StartDate, 
                     vw_Coords.TARGET_ID AS CoordID, vw_RegDirs.TARGET_ID AS 
   RDID
   FROM            Name INNER JOIN
                     Tops_Profile ON dbo.Name.ID = Tops_Profile.ID left 
   outer JOIN
                     vw_mz_rpt_leader_log rpt ON Name.CO_ID = rpt.ID LEFT 
   OUTER JOIN
                     vw_RegDirs ON Name.CO_ID = vw_RegDirs.CHAPTER LEFT 
   OUTER JOIN
                     vw_Coords ON Name.CO_ID = vw_Coords.CHAPTER LEFT OUTER 
   JOIN
                     Tops_Chapter ON Tops_Chapter.ID = Name.CO_ID
   WHERE        (Name.MEMBER_TYPE = 'm') AND (Tops_Profile.LDR = '1') and 
   LOG_TEXT like '%LEADER Change%'

   union 

   SELECT        Name.CO_ID, Name.FULL_NAME, Name.ID, 
   YEAR(dbo.Tops_Chapter.PST_DATE_LEAD) AS StartDate, 
                     vw_Coords.TARGET_ID AS CoordID, vw_RegDirs.TARGET_ID AS 
   RDID
   FROM            Name INNER JOIN
                     Tops_Profile ON Name.ID = Tops_Profile.ID left outer 
   JOIN
                     vw_mz_rpt_leader_log rpt ON Name.CO_ID = rpt.ID LEFT 
   OUTER JOIN
                     vw_RegDirs ON Name.CO_ID = vw_RegDirs.CHAPTER LEFT 
   OUTER JOIN
                     vw_Coords ON Name.CO_ID = vw_Coords.CHAPTER LEFT OUTER 
   JOIN
                     Tops_Chapter ON Tops_Chapter.ID = Name.CO_ID
   WHERE        (Name.MEMBER_TYPE = 'm') AND (Tops_Profile.LDR = '1')
```

the scope is if the record exists in the first query don't bring it from second query.

Comment: Some sample data and expected results would be great here. We don't have access to your data, so we can't run the query you have.[Forum Etiquette: How to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: So no matter what date, log has always precedence over profile. Yes? Can there be multiple rows for one name in the log query? Can there be multiple rows for one name in the profile query?

Comment: On a sidenote: Are you sure your joins are correct? A name.id should identify a name record; a log.id should identify a log record; a profile.id should identify a profile record; but you treat them as if they referred to the same thing. I'd expect something like `inner join log on name.id = log.name_id`.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner was a quick example but i updated my post with actual query. yes log have multiple rows for one name in profile should be one row for each name.

Comment: Actual query broke all the existing answers

Comment: i thought there was a simple solution didn't bother to bring the whole query on table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have altered your request. Suddenly both queries select from the same tables and a `UNION` (or `UNION ALL` for that matter) doesn't seem a good solution anymore.

There are very few differences between the two queries even. And looking at the whole it boils down to: select records for `member_type = 'm' and tp.ldr = 1` and then keep only one record per name, preferredly one with `log_text like '%LEADER Change%'`. This is mere ranking, as already shown in my other answer. You only need one query to select all records in question and use `TOP (1) WITH TIES` to keep the best matches per name.

```
select top(1) with ties
  n.co_id,
  n.full_name,
  n.id,
  case when log_text like '%LEADER Change%' then rpt.date else year(tc.pst_date_lead) end
    as startdate,
  c.target_id as coordid,
  rd.target_id as rdid
from name n
inner join tops_profile tp on n.id = tp.id
left outer join vw_mz_rpt_leader_log rpt on n.co_id = rpt.id
left outer join vw_regdirs rd on n.co_id = rd.chapter
left outer join vw_coords c on n.co_id = c.chapter
left outer join tops_chapter tc on tc.id = n.co_id
where n.member_type = 'm'
  and tp.ldr = 1
order by row_number() over (
             partition by n.id
             order by case when log_text like '%LEADER Change%' then 1 else 2 end);
```

As you said you just want only one record per name, I am using `ROW_NUMBER`. If you want more, use `RANK` instead.

It's not clear why you are joining the `tops_chapter` table. Is `log_text` a column in that table? (You should use a table qualifier for this column in your query.) If it isn't, then the join is superfluous and you can remove it from your query.

Comment: Worked!. this method return result way faster than union. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty way...

```
select *
from
(select id, Name, log.Date 
from Name
inner join Log on Name.id = log.id
where log.text_log like '%Leader%'
union
select id, Name, Profile.Date 
from Name
inner join profile on Name.id = profile.id
where profile.Leader = '1') d
order by row_number() over(partition by x.id order by x.Date asc)
```

Note, this doesn't care where John came from, it's simply finding the first occurrence based on the date which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Same thing didn't fix the issue. note the relationship is btw two records. I updated my post with the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number` and select id's with least date

```
with cte as
(select id, Name, log.Date 
from Name
inner join Log on Name.id = log.id
where log.text_log like '%Leader%'
union all
select id, Name, Profile.Date as log.date
from Name
inner join profile on Name.id = profile.id
where profile.Leader = '1' 
) , ct1 as (select id,name,log.date, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by log.date) rn from cte )

select id,name,log.date from ct1 where rn = 1
```

Comment: same result. Updated my post with actual query.

Answer (score 0):

```
where profile.Leader = '1'  
  and id not in ( select Name.id
                  from Name
                  inner join Log 
                     on Name.id = log.id
                  where log.text_log like '%Leader%' )
```

Comment: Not sure I believe that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` in the second query to filter out already existing `Name` records:

```
select id, Name, log.Date 
from Name
inner join Log on Name.id = log.id
where log.text_log like '%Leader%'

union

select n1.id, n1.Name, Profile.Date 
from Name as n1
inner join profile on n1.id = profile.id
where profile.Leader = '1' and 
      not exists (select 1
                  from Name as n2
                  inner join Log on n2.id = Log.id
                  where Log.text_log like '%Leader%' and 
                        n2.id = n1.id and n2.name = n1.name)
```

Comment: tried it and nothing shown. the text log is for a record diffirent then profile leader. I updated my post with the actual query.

Answer (score 0):

The query below finds logdate and profiledate for each name. If there is a logdate, the logdate will be diplayed else the profile date will be displayed. If both don't exist the Name won't be displayed.

```
select id, Name, coalesce(log.Date,profile.date)
from Name
left join Log on Name.id = log.id and log.text_log like '%Leader%'
left join profile on Name.id = profile.id and profile.Leader = '1'
where coalesce(log.Date,profile.date) is not null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rank to your two queries. Then per ID you keep the record(s) with the better rank (using `ORDER BY` with `TOP (1) WITH TIES`).

```
select top(1) with ties
  id, name, date
from
(
  select n.id, n.name, log.date, 1 as rnk
  from name n
  inner join log on name.id = log.id
  where log.text_log like '%Leader%'
  union all
  select n.id, n.name, profile.date, 2 as rnk
  from name n
  inner join profile on name.id = profile.id
  where profile.leader = '1'
) data
order by rank() over (partition by id order by rnk);
```

Comment: Tried it same issue. please see my post for the actual query.

Comment: Then you made a mistake. This query does give you the `text_log like '%Leader%'` records if available for a name and the `leader = '1'` records otherwise. As you have completely changed the query in your request, though, I've posted another answer. Same technique, only adjusted to the new query.